# Decrypting multiple files using cryptography.fernet

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, fernet

I am trying to write a code where I can decrypt multiple messages at once from a subdirectory.

I created a key directory and a message directory. The key directory contains subdirectories with .key files containing the decryption key.

The message directory contains subdirectories with .key files containing encrypted messages.

When I choose a subdirectory I want the code to decrypt all messages in that subdirectory. At the moment it only decrypts one file of the chosen subdirectory. The key and the encrypted file have the same name.

Can anyone help me with this? - beginning noob programmer

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
import glob

mainfolderlocation = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
keyfolderlocation = mainfolderlocation+'\Keys'
messagefolderlocation = mainfolderlocation+'\Messages' 

folder = input('Choose folder:\n')
            try:
                os.chdir(messagefolderlocation+'\{}'.format(folder))
                for file in glob.glob('*.key'):
                    filem = open(file, 'rb')
                    encrypted = filem.read()
                    filem.close()
                    filename= os.path.splitext(file)[0]

                os.chdir(keyfolderlocation+'\{}'.format(folder))    
                for file in glob.glob(filename+'.key'):
                    filek = open(file, 'rb')
                    key = filek.read()
                    filek.close()

                    f = Fernet(key)
                    decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted)
                    decode=decrypted.decode('utf-8')           
                    print(decode)

            except:
                print('\nThis folder does not exist!')
```

Comment: *...Can anyone help me with this?...* What is the problem?

Comment: I want the script to decrypt all the files in a subdirectory. But at the moment only one file from the subdirectory is picked and then it stops.

Answer (score 1):

your issue seems to be that there is an error with your loop. I do not have much experience with glob but you may want to try something like this:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
import glob

mainfolderlocation = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
keyfolderlocation = mainfolderlocation+'\Keys'
messagefolderlocation = mainfolderlocation+'\Messages' 

files = []

folder = input('Choose folder:\n')
os.chdir(keyfolderlocation+'\{}'.format(folder))    
for file in glob.glob(file+'.key'):
    filek = open(file, 'rb')
    key = filek.read()
    filek.close()

if os.path.exists(folder):
    for r, d, f in os.walk(folder):
        for file in f:
            if '.key' in file:
                files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
else:
    print('\nThis folder does not exist!')

for i in files:
    try:
        filem = open(i, 'rb')
        encrypted = filem.read()
        filem.close()
        filename= os.path.splitext(i)[0]



        f = Fernet(key)
        decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted)
        decode=decrypted.decode('utf-8')           
        print(decode)

    except:
        print('\nThis folder does not exist!')
```

So essentially what happens is you grab whatever your key is (beware that currently if you have more than one .key file you will have issues), make a list of all the files in the folder directory if it exists, and then for each one of those files you open it, read the contents, decrypt it and print it. I did not get a chance to test it out.

You also may want to consider putting your decryption in a function and calling it on each file instead of having it be monolithic but that's just a stylistic choice. Also I put the key grabbing above the try block because you only want to grab the key once otherwise you'll waste performance setting a variable to the same value. Unless you're using a different key file for each file in which case you may want to make dictionaries for each pair so 'bananasandwich.txt' is corresponding to 'bananasandwich.key'. Best of luck!

Comment: I thinks this might work. Only issue is that variable 'file' is not defined.

Comment: It was not defined before line 13, you'll need to create a method to define 'file' before calling it as a variable.